# Errors occur when include many 3rd party jars to one simple spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Whether it's possible to use API from one JAR from myself, while not include its dependency?

I created one standalone maven project(A) which is an API module and it uses many 3rd party jars and should be used in several projects. But in one spring boot project(B), since A introduced its dependencies, the spring boot project cannot work well.

If A is excluded from pom, then spring boot works well. But I do need several APIs from it. How should I solve this problem?

At first, everything works well. It is a pure console application.
Pom is something like below.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     -->
    <!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>InsuranceWrapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>InsuranceWrapper</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
     --> 
    </dependencies>
```

Then I add InsuranceWrapper to it, it will has one error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration$TransactionManagementConfiguration due to org/springframework/web/servlet/view/freemarker/FreeMarkerConfigurer not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:55) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/view/freemarker/FreeMarkerConfigurer
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:609) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

Then I thought spring boot may think I am a web project. So I add spring boot web. Now another error occurs.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor.getValidationMode(PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor.java:99) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
```

Searched these errors, no clues at all. My A project is a complex spring+hibernate project. That's why I ask this question and just want a clean environment for B while use several APIs from A.

**UPDATE**

add spring-boot-starter-freemarker to fix first error

**UPDATE**

Update mvn tree

```
    [INFO] net.ebaolife:EBTasks:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.16:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:8.0.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.0.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.23:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.0.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.0.30:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- com.dangdang:elastic-job-core:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.16.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- jline:jline:jar:0.9.94:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.netty:netty:jar:3.7.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.dangdang:elastic-job-spring:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:3.2.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.38:compile
[INFO] +- org.mongodb.morphia:morphia:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.thoughtworks.proxytoys:proxytoys:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- eu.bitwalker:UserAgentUtils:jar:1.18:compile
[INFO] \- InsuranceWrapper:InsuranceWrapper:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- ebcore:ebcore:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.jdom:jdom2:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO]    |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.acegisecurity:acegi-security:jar:1.0.7:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-remoting:jar:1.2.9:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-support:jar:1.2.9:runtime
[INFO]    |  |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.aliyun.openservices:aliyun-openservices:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- asm:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.7:compile
[INFO]    |  +- aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:cglib:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.cometd.java:cometd-api:jar:1.0.beta8:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:cometd-server:jar:6.1.17:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util5:jar:6.1.17:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-discovery:commons-discovery:jar:0.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.hynnet:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.xhtmlrenderer:core-renderer:jar:R8:compile
[INFO]    |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.directwebremoting:dwr:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:jar:1.0.2.GA:compile
[INFO]    |  +- net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.4.0.GA:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-search:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-tools:jar:3.2.4.GA:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.hibernate:jtidy:jar:r8-20060801:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.2.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO]    |  +- javassist:javassist:jar:3.11.0.GA:compile
[INFO]    |  +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.6:compile
[INFO]    |  +- axis:axis-jaxrpc:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- jboss:jboss-archive-browsing:jar:2.0.2.alpha:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.51:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.json:json:jar:20140107:compile
[INFO]    |  +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:jar:2.6.10:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.6:compile
[INFO]    |  +- jsptags:pager-taglib:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.belerweb:pinyin4j:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.12:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-scratchpad:jar:3.12:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.code.simple-spring-memcached:spymemcached:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.struts:struts2-core:jar:2.3.24.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.struts.xwork:xwork-core:jar:2.3.24.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     \- asm:asm-commons:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO]    |  |        \- asm:asm-tree:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.struts:struts2-json-plugin:jar:2.3.24.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.struts:struts2-spring-plugin:jar:2.3.24.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- redis.clients:jedis:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- ebao:tk-filters:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- ebao:flexjson:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- ebao:QRCode:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- ebao:java_memcached:jar:release_2.6.6:compile
[INFO]    |  +- ebao:jbarcode:jar:0.2.8:compile
[INFO]    |  +- ebao:jdbc2.0:jar:stdext:compile
[INFO]    |  \- ebao:lylab:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- ebao:cxf:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.ws.commons.schema:XmlSchema:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.axis:axis:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-core:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO]    |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO]    |  \- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-aegis:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO]    |  \- net.java.dev.stax-utils:stax-utils:jar:20040917:compile
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-java5:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-annotations:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- commons-attributes:commons-attributes-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     \- qdox:qdox:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]    |  \- xfire:xfire-jsr181-api:jar:1.0-M1:compile
[INFO]    \- org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-xmlbeans:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO]       \- xmlbeans:xbean:jar:2.2.0:compile
```

**UPDATE**

ADD below two exclusions, there are no errors now.

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

But since spring web is included.. It will start one tomcat from behind, which is very annoying..

**UPDATE**

Since any spring-web will make spring boot think now it is a web project, at last all spring web is removed. And also  spring-boot-starter-freemarker is removed either, since it is not used actually.

```
<exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
```

**All works now..**

Comment: can you provide Maven build messages?

Comment: It's hard to provide a good answer without some more specifics. It would be useful to know which dependency, when added to your API project, causes the problem. It would also be useful to know how Spring Boot isn't working well. What problem does the dependency it cause?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson It shows several different errors when I try to exclude jars from A or, add jars to B. I will modify question to add more details.

Comment: Maybe you can add project A dependency and exclude all his dependecies as described in http://stackoverflow.com/q/547805/3963330

Comment: Can you try adding dependency to org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker

Comment: @Tobías, I think it maybe a doable way, just exclude all dependencies and add necessary jars one by one.

Comment: The second error is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167945/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-spi-persistenceunitinfo-getvalida. It would appear that the `InsuranceWrapper` dependency is pulling in the JPA 1.0 API. Spring Boot requires JPA 2 (or no JPA dependencies at all if you don't want to use JPA). The first error is very strange. Can you share the output of `mvn dependency:tree` please?

Comment: @atao first error is gone. And the second error is out

Comment: @AndyWilkinson updated

Comment: Glad to see you got things working. InsuranceWrapper has some _very_ old dependencies. There's some Spring Framework 1.2 jars in there, for example. I'd recommend looking through all of them and updating/removing if possible any that are really old. Acegi Security is another. It's what became Spring Security.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. This project is very old and not well organized, too much things existing in it.I will look into it throughtly and try to decouple it .

Answer (score 0):

To exclude any file from a jar / target directory you can use the `<excludes>` tag in your pom.xml file.

In the next example, all files with `.properties` extension will not be included:

```xml
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Also check out this

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>sample.ProjectE</groupId> <!-- Exclude Project-E from Project-B -->
          <artifactId>Project-E</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Comment: strange answer: the issue is about dependency but the exemple is about resource...

Comment: It's just a sample, he can exclude other files which are not used.

Comment: how can i exclude all(or some) dependencies of A , while compile for B is successfully? May you help to explain a little bit for your answer? tks :)