# Missing JPA Dependency in Spring project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I am trying to deploy a spring based web-app on a Tomcat server, and I am unable to autowire an EntityManager. The root cause is a NoSuchMethodError.

I am assuming that I have the incorrect hibernate JARs as dependencies. Any help would be appreciated

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
```

I saw a previous post that pointed out that the issue was the inclusion of the following dependency, however, I am not including that one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Here are my POM dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167945/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-spi-persistenceunitinfo-getvalida

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167945/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-spi-persistenceunitinfo-getvalida)

Comment: i actually looked into that answer, but it doesn't seem to be my exact issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to check all different jars for  PersistenceUnitInfo class in your classpath.

I  hope you already know method getValidationMode exists only since JPA 2.

Not you need to find how many versions of this you have in your depenedency.

Thus if you are using tool (eclipse/intellij), you will be able to see a depndency hieracy/ effective pom and can see which dependency is used . And you can start from there and then you will be able to know there must be a older/invalid version which causes this kind of issue, then exclude that version from its parent dependency.
Or simply run in your command prompt/terminal to analyze it.

```
mvn dependency:analyze
```