# spring boot kotlin error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

Hi I am trying to build an application using kotlin and spring boot while running postgres image on docker but I keep getting this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
```

.....

this is my entity

```
@Entity
data class User(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    val id: Long,
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val age:Int,
    val gender:String
    )
```

this is my repository

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository

@Repository
interface UserRepository : JpaRepository<User, Long>
```

and this is my controller

```
@RestController
class UserRestController {


    @Autowired
    lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addUser")
    fun save(): User {

        return userRepository.save(User(id=1,firstName = "chaima",lastName = "ennar",age = 20,gender = "female"))

    }


}
```

those are my properties

```
server.port=${PORT:9000}
spring.cache.cache-names=googleFeeds,internationalFeeds
spring.cache.caffeine.spec=maximumSize=100,expireAfterAccess=1800s
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/irooldb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

and for my dependencies

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rometools</groupId>
            <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
            <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

My question is: what does this error means? and what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a duplicate of this issue: [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167945/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-spi-persistenceunitinfo-getvalida)

It appears that you are picking up JPA v1 libraty from your runtime classpath but the method that you are attempting to invoke was ony defined in JPA v2