# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError | Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to connect to a database using Spring. Unfortunately, it always gives me the error message, can that it could not find a certain method.
Incidental information that may not hurt. The program is complied with Java 8 . Accordingly, the server also runs on Java 8

Thanks for the help!

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWwIt.png)

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '7.1.2'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'io.github.rysefoxx'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()

    maven {
        url "https://repo.codemc.org/repository/maven-public/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly files('lib/spigot.jar')
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'

    implementation 'io.github.rysefoxx:RyseInventory-Plugin:1.1.9-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'io.github.rysefoxx:Hologram:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'net.wesjd:anvilgui:1.5.3-SNAPSHOT'

    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.5.Final'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:5.6.5.Final'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.6.7'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:2.6.7'

    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-aspects:5.3.19'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.28'

    implementation 'org.reflections:reflections:0.10.2'


    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.13.2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.13.2'

    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
}

shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

spring.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/home
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/home
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

spring.factories:

```
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport=org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory
org.springframework.data.util.ProxyUtils$ProxyDetector=org.springframework.data.jpa.util.HibernateProxyDetector
# Initializers
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SharedMetadataReaderFactoryContextInitializer,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener,\
org.springframework.boot.context.ConfigurationWarningsApplicationContextInitializer,\
org.springframework.boot.context.ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer,\
org.springframework.boot.context.config.DelegatingApplicationContextInitializer,\
org.springframework.boot.rsocket.context.RSocketPortInfoApplicationContextInitializer,\
org.springframework.boot.web.context.ServerPortInfoApplicationContextInitializer
# Application Listeners
org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.BackgroundPreinitializer,\
org.springframework.boot.ClearCachesApplicationListener,\
org.springframework.boot.builder.ParentContextCloserApplicationListener,\
org.springframework.boot.cloud.CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor,\
org.springframework.boot.context.FileEncodingApplicationListener,\
org.springframework.boot.context.config.AnsiOutputApplicationListener,\
org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener,\
org.springframework.boot.context.config.DelegatingApplicationListener,\
org.springframework.boot.context.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener,\
org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener,\
org.springframework.boot.liquibase.LiquibaseServiceLocatorApplicationListener
# Auto Configuration Import Listeners
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportListener=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionEvaluationReportAutoConfigurationImportListener
# Auto Configuration Import Filters
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportFilter=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnClassCondition,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnWebApplicationCondition
# Auto Configure
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=io.github.rysefoxx.spring.SpringSpigotAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.LifecycleAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.couchbase.CouchbaseAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.dao.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraReactiveDataAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraReactiveRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jdbc.JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hazelcast.HazelcastAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hazelcast.HazelcastJpaDependencyAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.influx.InfluxDbAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.XADataSourceAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.JooqAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jsonb.JsonbAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.availability.ApplicationAvailabilityAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.quartz.QuartzAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.rsocket.RSocketMessagingAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.rsocket.RSocketRequesterAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.rsocket.RSocketServerAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.rsocket.RSocketStrategiesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.rsocket.RSocketSecurityAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sendgrid.SendGridAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.solr.SolrAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.JtaAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration
# Failure analyzers
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzer=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisUrlSyntaxFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.diagnostics.analyzer.NoSuchBeanDefinitionFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationScriptMissingFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBeanCreationFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.HikariDriverConfigurationFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.NonUniqueSessionRepositoryFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.context.properties.NotConstructorBoundInjectionFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.BeanCurrentlyInCreationFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.BeanDefinitionOverrideFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.BindFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.BindValidationFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.UnboundConfigurationPropertyFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.ConnectorStartFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.NoSuchMethodFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.PortInUseFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.ValidationExceptionFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.InvalidConfigurationPropertyNameFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.analyzer.InvalidConfigurationPropertyValueFailureAnalyzer
# Temcensored availability providers
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.temcensored.TemcensoredAvailabilityProvider=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerTemcensoredAvailabilityProvider,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheTemcensoredAvailabilityProvider,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.temcensored.GroovyTemcensoredAvailabilityProvider,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafTemcensoredAvailabilityProvider
# PropertySource Loaders
org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourceLoader=\
org.springframework.boot.env.PropertiesPropertySourceLoader,\
org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader
# Run Listeners
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener=\
org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener
# Error Reporters
org.springframework.boot.SpringBootExceptionReporter=\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers
# Environment Post Processors
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=\
org.springframework.boot.cloud.CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor,\
org.springframework.boot.env.SpringApplicationJsonEnvironmentPostProcessor,\
org.springframework.boot.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySourceEnvironmentPostProcessor,\
org.springframework.boot.reactor.DebugAgentEnvironmentPostProcessor
# FailureAnalysisReporters
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalysisReporter=\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter
org.springframework.beans.BeanInfoFactory=org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167945/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-spi-persistenceunitinfo-getvalida

Comment: I agree with @Aman that the issue they linked is similar.  @Rysefoxx, it appears you have a transitive dependency on a version of the javax.persistence-api.persistence-api less than version 2.0.  Are you able to use `gradle dependencies` task to debug the dependency tree manually to root out the culprit dependency adding an older version of persistence-api to your classpath?  I believe that is what is causing your spring-boot 2.6.7 to fail autoconfiguration as spring-boot 2.6.7 will bring in a peristence-api version of 2.2 itself.

Comment: @krlittle Thanks for your help. I have tried a bit but still have not found a solution. I have looked with gradle dependencies. There I looked for the javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api and found that I have 2.2. So it should work or not?

Comment: @Rysefoxx would you mind editing your post to add the results from running the ‘gradle dependencies’ task?

Comment: @krlittle Of course. Unfortunately, the post is then too long. Therefore, here once the tree in hastebin. https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/inulawuzil.less

Answer (score 0):

It's not unlikely to be a problem caused by the [Shadow Plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow), it has a hurdle: You have to tell it how to handle file collisions, i.e. files with the same name. While this is not hard, and you already did it *partially* ( `mergeServiceFiles()`), I use it with Gradle Kotlin DSL like:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<ShadowJar> {
    mergeServiceFiles()
    append("META-INF/spring.handlers")
    append("META-INF/spring.schemas")
    append("META-INF/spring.tooling")
    transform(
        PropertiesFileTransformer().apply {
            paths = mutableListOf("META-INF/spring.factories")
            mergeStrategy = "append"
        })
}
```

It doesn't tell in its current version when such a conflict occurs, so you have to waste big amounts of time finding the conflicts yourself. But there is a pull request that it tells if there is a collision: https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/pull/773.
Until the pull request gets merged you could use the forked branch to be always informed about file collisions: https://github.com/JD-CSTx/shadow/tree/chapmajs-collision_logging.

Maybe I'm guessing wrong, and your problem is caused by something else, but this looks definitely like it could come from file collisions.